# How to save query result using T-SQL in a csv file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to save query result using T-SQL in a csv file in SSMS 2008? Needs to be done programmatically.

Comment: I specifically said using T-SQL. Programmatically. Which means not through the GUI.

Comment: "In SSMS" MS suggests Management Studio to me.

Comment: The query window in SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use System.Diagnostics.Process to run the SQLCMD or OSQL  or BCP programs to dump out csv files.

Comment: Agree BCP is simplest way; this is a good primer http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

If BCP isnt an option then a CLR function would let you do it too.

Comment: osql and bcp can't be run from the query window as these are command line programs. sqlcmd could work if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I found from google. Play around with the parameters.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -X -S server -q "SET NOCOUNT ON Select 'department','FundCode','Month' SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.test" -s , -w 255 -u -o "\\server\output.csv" -h-1'
```